# +entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Scores'

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm new to Objective C, iOS and CoreData and I'm currently trying to save some data to my Entity in CoreData.

When trying to find the entity with `insertNewObjectForEntityForName`, it looks like it is returning `nil` based on the error below.

**Error:**

```
2015-04-06 17:46:12.274 Bugland[18623:607] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Scores''
```

**LeaderboardViewController.m**

```
    JPAppDelegate *JPAppDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    
    NSManagedObjectContext *context =[JPAppDelegate managedObjectContext];
    
    NSManagedObject *newScore;
    newScore = [NSEntityDescription
                insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Scores"
                inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newScore setValue: scoreToAddAsString forKey:@"score"];
    NSError *error;
    [context save:&error];
```

Comment: Debug, check the `context` exists. Any errors logged before the crash?

Comment: What is the best way to check the value and/or if context exists? Just log it to the console or?

Comment: Sure, or add a breakpoint and `po`

Comment: Ok so if I comment out everything below where I define `*context`, I don't get the crash, and if I try log the context, I get nothing to the console. Hmm

Comment: So you need to look at + show your `managedObjectContext` method implementation and see if your Core Data stack is being set up at all

Comment: Hey Wain, thanks. Here is a gist explaining the setup. https://gist.github.com/jamespember/4aee343d73ebcd7f7b3f Let me know if you see anything that seems to be missing! Thanks :)

Comment: What else is in JPAppDelegate.m ?

Comment: Here you go https://gist.github.com/jamespember/05d853353515e26ffeaa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so, not that the app delegate should own the core data stack, but at the moment you have it doing so, and the instance that owns the core data stack needs to create the stack - at the moment nothing is doing that.

All you have is

```
@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

which just creates some accessor methods. Nothing ever sets those instance variables.

You should have some code like the below behemoth, see also [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/stack.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008283-SW1).

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {

    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        _managedObjectContext = [NSManagedObjectContext new];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
    }
    return _managedObjectContext;
}

/**
 Returns the managed object model for the application.
 If the model doesn't already exist, it is created by merging all of the models found in the application bundle.
 */
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {

    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    _managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}

/**
 Returns the URL to the application's documents directory.
 */
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}

/**
 Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
 If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.
 */
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {

    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    // copy the default store (with a pre-populated data) into our Documents folder
    //
    NSString *documentsStorePath =
        [[[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Recipes.sqlite"];

    // if the expected store doesn't exist, copy the default store
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:documentsStorePath]) {
        NSString *defaultStorePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Recipes" ofType:@"sqlite"];
        if (defaultStorePath) {
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:defaultStorePath toPath:documentsStorePath error:NULL];
        }
    }

    _persistentStoreCoordinator =
        [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

    // add the default store to our coordinator
    NSError *error;
    NSURL *defaultStoreURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:documentsStorePath];
   if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                  configuration:nil
                                                            URL:defaultStoreURL
                                                        options:nil
                                                          error:&error]) {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.

         Typical reasons for an error here include:
         * The persistent store is not accessible
         * The schema for the persistent store is incompatible with current managed object model
         Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    // setup and add the user's store to our coordinator
    NSURL *userStoreURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"UserRecipes.sqlite"];
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                                     configuration:nil
                                                                               URL:userStoreURL
                                                                           options:nil
                                                                             error:&error]) {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.

         Typical reasons for an error here include:
         * The persistent store is not accessible
         * The schema for the persistent store is incompatible with current managed object model
         Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

Comment: Ah, that code in addition to importing the coredata framework to the implementation file, no crashes. Ok now to the next job, checking out the database :) 

Thanks!